# forms appear poorly scaled at runtime

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, autoscaling

I have created a form in visual studio (vb.net winforms) and it looks great in designer however at runtime it appears extremely out of scale (on my computer only) - my computer is using resolution of 3840x2160 with DPI scaling of 250% - this is obviously the problem how do I make my application deal with this better?

I have tried using Autoscalemode, autosize, and autosizemode with the form only appearing more broken than it currently does.

Here is the appearance in designer:
[image: Designer]

Here is the appearance at runtime on my computer:
[image: runtime]

Comment: You could try `TableLayoutPanel` but Winforms and scaling don't play very well together.

Comment: `.AutoScroll = True` might also help on your tab controls. I'd try that first

Answer (score 1):

Is your application DPI Aware? Read this article for more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn469266(v=vs.85).aspx

Basically you want to add this to your `app.manifest` inside the `<asmv1:assembly>` block:

```
 <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
```

Comment: this appears to be default as it already exists in my manifest

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you didn't change the default anchor property of the tools. Also make sure that you don't change location or size of the tools at runtime.